# BCM4311 "wireless is disabled by a hardware switch"

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, broadcom

I am running a HP Pavilion dv6000 with BCM4311.  I am new to ubuntu and admittedly am rather unfamiliar with running code in terminal.  I have tried a dozen different ways i have found online and nothing works.  I have disabled the Broadcom STA driver and reisntalled b43-fwcutter.  It runs a wired connection but it is hardblocked and have been getting frustrated.

any help?

thanks yal

Comment: 0: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: +1. Broadcom wireless chips cause frustration to the whole world. Your chip should be [fully supported](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Supported_devices) by [b43 drivers](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43), so don't give up and keep trying! I also have a supported chip, the BCM43225, and I still don't have a working b43 driver. But I'll keep trying from time to time, just to not let Broadcom win :)

Answer (score 0):

try running the following from terminal window:

```
SUDO RFKILL UNBLOCK ALL
```

This worked for me. Make sure the hardware switch is on when you run this command. good luck.